# $n$-th term of an infinite sequence

Tags: calculus

Determine the $n$-th term of the sequence $1/2,1/12,1/30,1/56,1/90,\ldots$. I have not been able to find the explicit formula for the $n$-th term of this infinite sequence. Can some one solve this problem and tell me how they find the answer?

Comment: Look at the denominator they are all even so divide them 2, to make it more obvious.

Comment: As with any "find the rule for the sequence" questions, without information as to what type of sequence it is in the first place, there is absolutely nothing stopping the next term in the sequence from being literally any number.  It is like asking "what is the next term of $1,1,2,3,5,8,13...$?" and it turns out not to be the Fibonacci sequence but instead the [Icanobof Sequence](http://oeis.org/A001129) with the next number being $39$, not $21$.

Comment: I agree with JMoravitz.  it's quite a stupid question to give any finite number of terms of a sequence and ask about the general formula.  There are, after all, infinitely many sequences with the same given finite terms.  I think this kind of questions should be regarded as "too broad."

Comment: The denominators are $1\times2$, $3\times4$, $5\times6$, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, they are $\dfrac11-\dfrac12$, $\dfrac13-\dfrac14$, $\dfrac15-\dfrac16$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would bet on the inverses of [OEIS A002939](http://oeis.org/A002939), so $a_n = \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}$  I just typed $2,12,30,56,90$ into the search box.  There were three hits.

Answer (score 3):

To find a formula you need to first find the pattern.

There are a number of ideas to use when trying to find for such paterns in a sequence:

- if all numbers are composite, try to factorise - if this works nicely a pattern may emerge at this stage, especially for numbers with one prime factor, e.g. $56 = 7 \times 8$
- often a sequence will be built on the natural numbers $1,2,3,\dots$ somehow
- use trial and error, and look at the context around the numbers for any clues

Using these ideas, you could come up with

- $2 = 1 \times 2$
- $12 = 3 \times 4$
- $30 = 5 \times 6$
- $56 = 7 \times 8$

If you want to pair these with the natural numbers to develop a formula, you will need to recognise that you are dealing with pairs of consecutive numbers that ascend by two from the previous pair.

$n: 1,2,3,4,5,\dots \\
2n: 2,4,6,8,10,\dots \\$

Hence, each pair is $\{2n-1,2n\}$.

Then $s_n = \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2n}$